# How to get specific text in a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="news"> 
       <script type="text/javascript">

           some codes

       </script>

           needed content

       <div class="seperator">

           unneeded content

       </div>

  unneeded content2

 </div>
```

I want to get just "needed content" here. So I have to delete script tags and get all text **till** `div.seperator`

If i get text just from the root (div.news) not included sub elements, i will solve  the problem or another way i have to clean sub elements.

How can i handle this problem.

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Writing an answer :)

Comment: Can you wrap needed content in a `<span>` (or any tags) and give it an ID or a class ? It'll be easier to target with `.text()`

Comment: Some searches on google would give you the answer to such a basic question ;) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** to get all nodes, including text nodes.  Then use `.not($('*'))` to exclude element nodes:

```js
console.log($('.news').contents().not($('*')).text().trim()); //needed content
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    some codes
  </script>

  needed content

  <div class="seperator">

    unneeded content

  </div>

</div>
```

---

Based on your updated post, you can use **[`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling)** to get the text node before `.seperator`:

```js
console.log($('.seperator')[0].previousSibling.textContent.trim()); //needed content
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    some codes
  </script>

  needed content

  <div class="seperator">

    unneeded content

  </div>

  unneeded content2
</div>
```

Comment: this is so useful for me thank you. just i want ask something important also . I update question now. is there any way to clean "unneeded content2" in this case?

Comment: likewise, I cannot believe this has had so little + votes, though likely its duplicated massively across Stack Overflow.. my first time using `contents()` now, in unison with `not($('*'))`, as suggested, and it is wonderful! thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `contents()` and `filter()` to retrieve the textNodes within an element. Try this:

```
var textNodes = $('.news').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() != ''
}).get();

console.log(textNodes[0].nodeValue.trim()); // = 'needed content'
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nmmpt94z/)

Comment: thank you so much this is good but there is a problem sometimes it may be  more than one  paragraph beetween script and div.seperator. so it depends for example like need content <br> need content2 .in this case this jquery will get just first need content but i need also second. is there any way to say get text till div.spereator my friend?

Comment: To do that you could use create an array of all the returned nodeValues from `text` and create a string by using `join()`, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/nmmpt94z/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.childNodes` of parent `DOM` element `.news` , select node at index `2`

```
$(".news")[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue.trim()
```

alternatively, using `for` loop on parent `.news` `.childNodes`, node where `.previousElementSibling` `.tagName` is `"SCRIPT"`

```js
var nodes = document.querySelector(".news").childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  if (nodes[i].previousElementSibling 
      && nodes[i].previousElementSibling.tagName === "SCRIPT") {
    console.log(nodes[i].nodeValue.trim());
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="news"> 
       <script type="text/javascript">

           //some codes

       </script>

           needed content

       <div class="seperator">

           unneeded content

       </div>

 </div>
```